# why is item not being deleted from dictionaries list values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary:

```
new_members = {'member1': ['PCP2'],
 'member10': ['PCP2'],
 'member13': ['PCP5'],
 'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
 'member5': ['PCP5'],
 'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
 'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4'],
 'member8': ['PCP5'],
 'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
```

and 2 set:

```
pcps_in_negative = {'PCP4'}
pcps_at_zero = {'PCP6'}
```

If an item from either set appears in any of the dictionary's list values, remove it.  So in this case, 'PCP4' should be removed from 'member7's list.

I tried

```
for k, v in new_members.items():
    for i in v:
        if i in pcps_at_zero or i in pcps_in_negative:
            v.remove(i)
```

But `new_members` items remains unchanged. "member7" should just have ['PCP2'].  This is a simple example. The sets `pcps_in_negative` and `pcp_at_zero` may have more items in another case.

Comment: Modifying the list that you iterate over is problematic and error-prone.

Comment: `v.remove(i) -> del new_members[i]`. Note what @Code-Apprentice said, though.

Comment: What *actually* happens: `NameError: name 'to_remove_zero' is not defined`

Comment: Is there a safer way to do this problem?  Removing an item from a list value of a dictionary if that item is in another list, or set.

Comment: *safer way* is while building `new_members` dont values that shouldn't be added.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Sorry I had changed to vaiable name for the post and forgot to change in the loop.  I edited the question

Comment: Ok, now what actually happens is that the value *does* get removed.

Comment: @HeapOverflow using remove() ?

Comment: @BenSmith Of course. Why would I change the code and not tell you?

Comment: @Ch3steR new_members is the product of an earlier process of my program.  I dont have control over this.  The program is whittling at an original dictionary of "members" and new_members was one outcome of an earlier process

Comment: @HeapOverflow because it doesnt work for me. Yes the variable names are consistent when I do it

Comment: @BenSmith I don't believe you. If it doesn't work for you, then you're not using what you're showing here.

Comment: @HeapOverflow its exactly as I've shown.  It shouldnt matter anyways because 'PCP6' isnt even anywhere in `new_members` so it changes nothing!

Comment: @BenSmith Not sure why you're now talking about PCP6. You said that PCP**4** doesn't get removed. Which isn't true.

Comment: @BenSmith Your code is working fine. So, what exactly is bugging you?

Comment: @Ch3steR It's bugging me that it remains the same on my end when I run the entire program

Comment: @BenSmith I ran your code on my machine. It worked how you intended it to work. Not sure what's wrong. May be other functions of your code are effecting.

Comment: @Ch3steR try adding a new element to pcps_at_negative such at 'PCP3' and tell me if that works for you.  If the set is longer than just one element it doesn  work

Comment: @BenSmith `PCP3` isn't even in any of the lists. And yes, I added `PCP3` to `pcps_in_negative` . Now `pcps_in_negative= {'PCP3', 'PCP4'}`. And It worked as intended it removed every instance of `PCP4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter each list from your dict:

```
bad_items = pcps_in_negative |  pcps_at_zero
new_members = {k: [e for e in v if e not in bad_items] for k, v in new_members.items()}
print(new_members)
```

**output:**

```
{'member1': ['PCP2'],
 'member10': ['PCP2'],
 'member13': ['PCP5'],
 'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
 'member5': ['PCP5'],
 'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
 'member7': ['PCP2'],
 'member8': ['PCP5'],
 'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import copy
for k, v in new_members.items():
    temp_list = copy.deepcopy(v)
    temp_list = [x for x in temp_list if x not in pcps_at_zero]
    temp_list = [x for x in temp_list if x not in pcps_in_negative]
    new_members[k] = temp_list
```

Final new_members dictionary becomes :

```
{'member1': ['PCP2'],
'member10': ['PCP2'],
'member13': ['PCP5'],
'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
'member5': ['PCP5'],
'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
'member7': ['PCP2'],
'member8': ['PCP5'],
'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: are you suing Python 3 ?

Comment: If you are on python 3 use `new_members.items()` instead. `.iteritems()` was renamed to `.items()` in python 3. `.iteritems()` works fine on my system with python2. :)

Comment: Will creating this temp_list bog down memory?  In reality the records in new_members will be in the thousands

Comment: There's no need to use copy.deepcopy as the lists are not nested; instead you could just use v.copy().

Comment: @CDJB There's no need for `copy`, either.

Comment: @HeapOverflow indeed, didn't see that v wasn't used!